# Copy and Paste into multiple text boxes c#

Tags: c#

I'm sure this is really simple to do but I'm struggling.

I've 6 Textboxes and I would like to copy them in Clipboard and paste them to others.

So to copy I do:

```cs
private void Btn_Copy_P1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder cop = new StringBuilder();
    cop.AppendLine(X_Point_1_Rob.Text);
    cop.AppendLine(Y_Point_1_Rob.Text);
    cop.AppendLine(Z_Point_1_Rob.Text);
    cop.AppendLine(Rx_Point_1_Rob.Text);
    cop.AppendLine(Ry_Point_1_Rob.Text);
    cop.AppendLine(Rz_Point_1_Rob.Text);

    Clipboard.SetText(sb.ToString());
}

private void Btn_Paste_P2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.GetText()

    // How it's possible to paste the 6 values from Clipboard ?
}
```

Do you have a working method or a solution?

Comment: Why using the clipboard when you can simply do `YourTextbox.Text = SomeText;`

Comment: It seems you already try to stuff all values into one string using a StringBuilder. If you include a delimiter (Like `|`) you could simply `Split` the string you get from the clipboard and use the individual values again. However it seems you are over complicating things unless you are trying to access a different application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
private void Btn_Paste_P2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] text = Clipboard.GetText()?.Split('\\n');
    
    if(text == null || text.Length == 0)
       return;

    X_Point_1_Rob.Text = text[0];
    Y_Point_1_Rob.Text = text[1]; 
    ...
    Rz_Point_1_Rob.Text = text[5];
}
```

By the way, where do you want to paste copied snippets of text?

Comment: It's working ! Thank you for your quick reply !!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution.

```cs
// Copy text to the clipboard.
private void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetText(txtCopy.Text);
}
```

```cs
// Paste text from the clipboard.
private void btnPaste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtPaste.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
}
```

For more info : [Copy and paste text to and from the clipboard C#](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/copy-and-paste-text-to-and-from-the-clipboard-c/)